# MongoDB - Java | Use of $near

Tags: java, mongodb, location

I am saving some posts in a MongoDB Collection like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56e7152edbaacc2ab1d34f20"
    },
    "title": "the title",
    "body": "the post",
    "loc": {
       "lat": 40.616856,
       "lng": 22.954689
    },
    "timestamp": "1457984814748",
    "username": "User",
    "fbID": "4324"
}
```

I want to get the posts that are around a specific ratio lets say 2km.

I am trying to find how the `$near` works but cannot find documentation about this function in mongodb java docs. If anybody knows how I can do this or where can I find some documentation about it would be much appreciated.

This is what i am trying so far where `texts` is the collection from the db:

```
        QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder();
        query.put("loc").near(22.9545545, 40.616479, 50);
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor2 = texts.find((BasicDBObject) query.get()).iterator();
        try {
            while (cursor2.hasNext()) {
                Document doc = cursor2.next();
                documents.add(doc);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor2.close();
        }
```

I also tried this:

```
Double locationLongitude = new Double (22.9545545);
                Double locationLatitude = new Double (40.616479);
                BasicDBObject  locQuery = new BasicDBObject ();
                locQuery.put("loc", new Document("$near", new Double[]{locationLongitude, locationLatitude}));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor2 = texts.find(locQuery).iterator();
            try {
                while (cursor2.hasNext()) {
                    Document doc = cursor2.next();
                    documents.add(doc);
                }
            } finally {
                cursor2.close();
            }
```

**UPDATE**

After a little research i came to this:

I changes my json documents to this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56e9e7440296451112edd05d"
    },
    "title": "ρ",
    "body": "ρ",
    "lng": 22.954689,
    "lat": 40.616856,
    "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            22.954689,
            40.616856
        ]
    },
    "timestamp": "1458169668154",
    "username": "User",
    "fbID": "4324"
}
```

and my java code to this:

```
        collection.createIndex(new Document("loc", "2dsphere"));
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(near("loc", 22.9548626, 40.6159144, 100.0, 0.0)).iterator();

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                Document doc = cursor.next();
                documents.add(doc);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

But still not getting any results.. cursor has no documents.
I am also getting this error

> 03-17 01:34:05.489 1786-1805/? W/System.err: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 17007 and error message 'Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=posts2.texts2 limit=0 skip=0
>   03-17 01:34:05.489 1786-1805/? W/System.err: Tree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=100 isNearSphere=0
>   03-17 01:34:05.489 1786-1805/? W/System.err: Sort: {}
>   03-17 01:34:05.489 1786-1805/? W/System.err: Proj: {}
>   03-17 01:34:05.489 1786-1805/? W/System.err:  planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query' on server ds011439.mlab.com:11439

Comment: Where is your Java code?

Comment: @Saleem i edited he question. Thanks for your response

Comment: There is a change in my json too. 'lng' and 'lat' is in "loc"

Comment: For basic info about the `$near` query, see official docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/. It's not about Java driver, but about mongo in general. Try using the mongo shell and run the query by hand until you are able to write the query yourself, and then shift to Java driver. Also, you could add some info on why/how your approaches fail.

Comment: error is self explanatory. `error: unable to find index for $geoNear query' on server ds011439.mlab.com:11439`. Not sure what's so difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is here
`MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(near("loc", 22.9548626, 40.6159144, 100.0, 0.0)).iterator();`

In your json format your "loc" field is type: Point. The `near` function has another constructor who is 
`near(String field, Point point, Double max, Double min)`
So instead of `22.9548626, 40.6159144,` you should use a `Point`.

You can create a Point like this:

```
Position position = new Position(22.9548626,40.6159144);
Point point = new Point(position);
```

[Here](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/model/geojson/Point.html) is the documenation.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting you shell query to help you understand how $near work.

First, you need to create `2dsphere` index on collection you want to run location aware queries. Assuming you location name is `loc`

```
db.loc.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})
```

After creation of index, execute following query

```
db.loc.find(
   {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ 40.617856, 22.954689 ] },
            $maxDistance: 2000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

It will search all location with in 2000 meters (2Km)

Comment: I updated my question, can you help me with what mught be the error? I think i am getting close. Thanks for your effort so far :)

Comment: To run GeoSpatial queries, you'll need to create `2dsphere` first. This is onetime operation.

Comment: I think i do create a 2d sphere index in `collection.createIndex(new Document("loc", "2dsphere"));` no ?

Comment: verify on your database if its get created or not. open shell, connect to your database and run `db.col_what_ever.getIndexes()`

Answer (score 0):

First Open a shell connection to your database and create the index.

```
db.Salons.createIndex({"loc":"2dsphere"});
```

When you want to index **nested object**:

```
db.Salons.createIndex({"address.loc":"2dsphere"});
```

This is an alternative way to query the $near

```
//Imports
import org.springframework.data.geo.Circle;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Distance;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Metrics;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
    ....
```

**Find salons near  a location**

```
Point point  = new Point(longitude, latitude);
List<Salon> salonsNear = mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria
                              .where("loc")
                              .near(point)
                              .maxDistance(100)), Salon.class);
```

**Find within a radius of 2km**

```
Double longitude = 4.368333;
Double latitude = 51.1981366;
Double distance  = 2.0;

Circle myCircle = new Circle(new Point(longitude, latitude), new Distance(distance, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
List<Salon> salonsWithinCircle = mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria
                                   .where("loc")
                                   .withinSphere(myCircle)), Salon.class);
```

Find within a radius of 2km for **nested objects**

```
Circle myCircle = new Circle(new Point(longitude, latitude), new Distance(distance, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
List<Salon> salonsWithinCircle = mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria
                                   .where("address.loc")
                                   .withinSphere(myCircle)), Salon.class);
```